# non of the endpoints are reachable rabbitmq clientm, i can not connect to the rabbit mq server from any vsto after installing it

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

've built a VSTO Outlook add-in in C# that integrates with my RabbitMQ broker using the RabbitMQClient library. During development within Visual Studio 2022, the connection functions as expected. However, after deploying the project using Wix and installing it on a different machine, I encounter the error "none of the endpoints are reachable" when attempting to create a channel and establish a connection factory.

Code Snippet:

```
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { 
        UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.rUser, 
        Password = Properties.Settings.Default.rPass, 
        VirtualHost = "/", 
        HostName = Properties.Settings.Default.hostName, 
        Port = 5672, 
      }; 
     return factory.CreateConnection();
```

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Connectivity: I've used telnet to confirm that port 5672 is open on the RabbitMQ host machine.
Credentials: I've verified that the hostname, username, and password stored in my settings are correct.
Suspicions and Questions:

Could there be dependency issues introduced by the Wix installer that are preventing the RabbitMQClient library from functioning correctly in the deployed environment?
Are there specific permissions or configurations that a VSTO Outlook add-in might require to establish network connections?
Has anyone encountered similar issues with VSTO add-ins and external network dependencies?
What debugging approaches or logging strategies would you recommend to pinpoint the root cause of this problem?

Environment:

Development: Visual Studio 2022
Deployment: Wix Installer
Target OS: Windows 11
Thank you for any insights or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

> Could there be dependency issues introduced by the Wix installer that are preventing the RabbitMQClient library from functioning correctly in the deployed environment?

No. Wix doesn't apply any rules to the deployed software.

> Are there specific permissions or configurations that a VSTO Outlook add-in might require to establish network connections? Has anyone encountered similar issues with VSTO add-ins and external network dependencies?

You may treat VSTO add-ins like regular .net applications.

> What debugging approaches or logging strategies would you recommend to pinpoint the root cause of this problem?

You may try using Fiddler or any other utility to track how network calls work and why they fail.

Comment: I checked fiddler , and everything seems normal when i preform the test on my local. but once i test  on other pcs no traffic can be detected bny fiddler ]

Comment: Do you run fiddler under the same security context with your application?

Comment: Yes i am using the same , and i tried to do the same on multiple devices with the same outcome